# Find a UITableView from code?

Tags: cocoa-touch, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

How do I connect a UITableView so I can find it in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll need to add what is called an outlet. I prefer to not use IB for my apps as there's less hocus pokus but if you do prefer to use interface Builder you'll need to read up on a few tutorials. There's a few here:

http://monotouch.net/Tutorials

The main steps (from memory) are:

1. add the tableview to your view
2. add an outlet to the parent view using the object explorer classes view
3. connect the tableview to the outlet using the connections view
4. save and exit IB
5. go back to MT and you'll be able to access the tableview using the name of the outlet you defined

here is a helo world tutorial using IB: http://monotouch.net/Tutorials/MonoDevelop_HelloWorld

hth :)

w://